# Echo only the day number

Tags: php, date, datetime

This is my code right now:

```
echo"<tr>
        <td>{$row['game_release']}</td>
    </tr>";
```

How do I echo only the day? For example 2015-05-06 should echo as only '6'?

This is the code I found on Stackoverflow, but couldn't get it to work:

```
$string = "2010-11-24";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
echo $date->format("d");
```

Comment: What is in `$row["game_release"]` ?

Comment: That's a date (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: What is the current output you're getting?

Comment: I've done  that now, the perks of being a newbie is  that you've got lots to learn ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just create a new [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, where I then simply [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) it with the format which you want.

```
echo"<tr>
    <td>" . (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j") . "</td>
</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'j' instead of 'd'

```
<?php
$string = "2010-11-06";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
echo $date->format("j");
?>
```

In you're example you could use:

```
$row['game_release'] = '2015-06-05';

echo"<tr>
        <td>" . date('j', strtotime($row['game_release'])) . "</td>
    </tr>";
```

assuming $row['game_release'] is a valid date.

Putting it together would make:

```
<?php
$row['game_release'] = '2015-06-05';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $row['game_release']);

echo"<tr>
        <td>{$date->format("j")}</td>
    </tr>";
```

Comment: This absolutely worked like a charm. Thanks so much! --> Edit: every date is shown as the fifth now (5).

Comment: `w` is the wrong format here for what OP wants (w is the numeric number for the day of the week e.g. 0-6 for `Sun-Mun`)

Comment: @Rizier123 you are right, OP should use 'j' will change post